# Cloudflare with Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, full-page-cache, cdn

Thinking about setting up Cloudflare for a Magento instance but not quite too sure how to handle caching with dynamic content. As every page has a basket total I cant see how page caching can be used.

Therefore the only real benefits of Cloudflare with Magento would be the added security and the CDN for the assets. However if the customer base is in the same country and the hosting solution the CDN for assets might not be that beneficial.

Am I missing something or is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

There is more to it than just caching such as image, session and browser optimisation. See more here - https://www.cloudflare.com/features-optimizer/

Answer (score 1):

You can load the cart via AJAX or even better: put it into the local storage and update it on ever add/remove/update

Comment: How would that work with form keys and sessions?

Comment: The easiest solution: it doesn't. But I think removing form key from add to cart is no security problem.